# Invalid data type in criteria expression for no reason

Tags: c#, wcf, ms-access, types

I have this unbelievably annoying issue with an Access db sitting on our server. It was working fine when yesterday it suddenly starting squatting out these

> Invalid data type in criteria expression

- So I tested on my machine - working fine
- Uploaded that working code to the server - same error
- Copied the db down to my machine - working fine

The only difference I can see between the data is that if I log the SQL query values to my error message I can see that a value for `Document Date` has a different format on my pc and on the server:

**server**

```
@documentDate : 2018-10-09 12:00:00 AM
```

**local machine**

```
@documentDate : 09/10/2018 12:00:00
```

All other values look exactly the same.

So is this an issue relating to locality/`DateTime` formats? If so, why can't Access just accept a `DateTime` value and store it appropriately, since that column is of data type `Date/Time`.

Would really appreciate some help on this it is driving my crazy.

Here is the code used to insert a record:

```
public int InsertAod(Aod aod)
{
    if (CheckAod(aod) > 0)
    {
        Log.Message("This entry already exists");
        return 1; 
    }

    var cmd = new OleDbCommand(Constants.InsertAod);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company", aod.ParentCollection.Company);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@businessUnit", aod.ParentCollection.BusinessUnit);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sellerGln", aod.ParentCollection.SellerGln);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@messageId", aod.ParentCollection.MessageId);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@documentNo", aod.ParentCollection.DocumentNumber);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@documentDate", aod.ParentCollection.DocumentDate); // Data type of DocumentDate is DateTime
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@region", aod.ParentCollection.Region);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@storeGln", aod.ParentCollection.StoreGln);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@storeCode", aod.ParentCollection.StoreCode);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@storeDescription", aod.ParentCollection.StoreDescription);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lineItem", aod.LineItem);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@movementType", aod.MovementType);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderNo", aod.OrderNumber);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reference", aod.ParentCollection.Reference);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@barcode", aod.Barcode);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@articleNo", aod.PnPArticleNumber);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vendorCode", aod.VendorProductCode);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@articleDescription", aod.PnPArticleDescription);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", aod.PnPQuantity);

    try
    {
        //throw new Exception("how is this possible");
        return ExecuteCommand(cmd, Execute.Insert);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var data = cmd.Parameters.Count.ToString();
        foreach (OleDbParameter parameter in cmd.Parameters)
        {
            data += $" {Environment.NewLine} {parameter.ParameterName} : {parameter.Value} {Environment.NewLine}";
        }
        Log.Error(e, $"Failed to insert AOD for {aod.OrderNumber} - {aod.LineItem}", data);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Here is the code for `CheckAod`:

```
public int CheckAod(Aod aod)
{
    var cmd = new OleDbCommand(Constants.CountAod);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderNo", aod.OrderNumber);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@messageId", aod.ParentCollection.MessageId);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lineItem", aod.LineItem);

    try
    {
        return ExecuteCommand(cmd, Execute.Count);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.Error(e, "Failed to call CheckAod");
        throw;
    }
}
```

And the `ExecuteCommand` mentioned above:

```
private int ExecuteCommand(OleDbCommand cmd, Execute command)
{
    var output = 0;
    if (!(persistantConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open))
        persistantConnection.Open();

    cmd.Connection = persistantConnection;
    using (cmd)
    {                
        try
        {
            switch (command)
            {
                case Execute.Insert:
                    output = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Log.Message("success");
                    break;
                case Execute.Count:
                    output = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var data = cmd.Parameters.Count.ToString();
            foreach (OleDbParameter parameter in cmd.Parameters)
            {
                data += $" {Environment.NewLine} {parameter.ParameterName} : {parameter.Value} {Environment.NewLine}";
            }
            Log.Error(e, "Failed to execute command", data);
            throw;
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

This is what `Constants.InsertAod` looks like:

```
internal const string InsertAod =
    @"INSERT INTO TAOD ([COMPANY], [BUSINESS UNIT], [SELLER GLN], [MESSAGE ID], [DOCUMENT NO],
        [DOCUMENT DATE], [REGION], [STORE GLN], [STORE CODE], [STORE DESCRIPTION], [LINE ITEM], 
        [MOVEMENT TYPE], [ORDER NO], [REFERENCE], [BARCODE], [PNP ARTICLE NO], 
        [VENDOR PRODUCT CODE], [PNP ARTICLE DESCRIPTION], [PNP QTY])
        VALUES (@company, @businessUnit, @sellerGln, @messageId, @documentNo, @documentDate, @region, 
        @storeGln, @storeCode, @storeDescription, @lineItem, @movementType, @orderNo, @reference,
        @barcode, @articleNo, @vendorCode, @articleDescription, @qty)";
```

And I can confirm that the above values are in the same order as they appear in the db itself.

Comment: How does Access "squat" an error?  *"squatting"* in my vocabulary means to sit.  Add an 'h' to that and I agree that Access is full of it, but it still doesn't help understand when the error occurs. When does the error appear?  When you load a form, run a query, thrown as an exception when accessed via ODBC from within a c# wpf application?  The question lacks details of the context.  It is tagged as c# and wcf, but the question indicates nothing to do with either of those.

Comment: @CPerkins The errors appear when I try to insert a record. As mentioned, this has always worked, and it works on my own machine, so it seems unlikely to be caused by the query itself. I've updated my question to include some details, but still it was working 1 day ago and I changed nothing, so my question is more about how this is actually possible. Squatting could also refer to the act of sitting with an 'h'

Comment: @Bassie - **(1)** Does your INSERT command text include the column names, e.g., `INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2, ...) VALUES (?, ?, ...)` as opposed to `INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (?, ?, ...)` ...? **(2)** Do your `Parameters.AddWithValue` statements appear in exactly the same order that the parameter placeholders appear in the command text? (Don't rely on the parameter names, only their positions.)

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks for your comment. I updated the question but (1)-I include the column names and (2)-They are in the correct order, but I am not including the `ID` or `CreateDate` columns as these are auto-generated and I have never included them in the past.

Comment: Random guess:  It is around this time of year that time zones change from daylight savings.  These rules were updated only a couple years ago and--as I observe--there are still some bugs being weeded out in software and OS's.  Perhaps your server's localization settings in combination with your particular time zone has experienced some weird bug where the OldDb objects are not properly formatting dates for daylight savings change??

Comment: In the event that you can't figure out why and what happened (or even if you do find out), I suggest using the `Parameter.Add()` overload that lets you **specify the precise datatype of the parameter**, rather than letting it be inferred by `AddWithValue()`.  There is already some ambiguity between date and time datatypes of database tables and if allowed to determine this dynamically based only upon the parameter value type, perhaps it is not choosing the correct or optimal database column type for every configuration (local vs server).

Comment: Worst case, go against the advise of the previous answer and explicitly format the DateTime value as a known, compatible string format, then update the query to do proper conversion on the query/Access side, perhaps using `CDate()` or `DateValue()`, etc.  I do not see major problems with this, since you're not necessarily opening it up to injection since you're forcibly converting a date value to a string value and still sending it as a parameter into the non-query.

Comment: The only code that seems to use "criteria" is the counting command, so you should check those parameters (`@orderNo`, `@messageId` and `@lineItem`). Maybe you can post the code of that command, too.

Comment: @WolfgangKais `Count` is just an enum used in `ExecuteCommand`, or did you mean something else? The items you mentioned are all being sent throuh as strings with the db expecting type text

Comment: @CPerkins Thanks for your comments, I will try playing with `Add()`. I'm in South Africa and we don't do daylight savings here - do you think that it could still potentially cause problems?

Comment: @WolfgangKais - The error message can be a bit misleading: "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" is also reported if we try to insert a string parameter whose value is `"Fred"` into an Access Date/Time column.

Comment: @Bassie - Perhaps you could add `parameter.DbType.ToString()` to your log output to ensure that your parameter values match the column type in the table.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, I managed to find the problem and posted it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of messing around I realised that the server was failing to convert the value `PnPQuantity` from `string` to `number` (the Access data type).

When I tried to do this explicitly I was getting this error

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Even though the string was in the form `"18.000"`

I changed my code to include a `CultureInfo` parameter:

```
decimal.Parse(aod.PnPQuantity, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

And it now works fine.

What I don't understand is why the machine suddenly can't handle converting a `18.000` to a number, when the localisation settings are configured to use `.` as a decimal seperator:

[image]

Also, since this was working fine a couple of days ago this means something must have changed on the server, but what could it possibly be?